# Extracting data from form in a sequence

Tags: javascript, sequence

i need some help with this, I've studied it on w3schools but didn't come across of anything similar.
The form needs to have two inputs, the date and the item. 10 dates in a row, 10 items. The date can be dropdown and the item in textarea.
Once the user selects a date and writes the item purchased, his choice needs to be written below the form. The tricky part is that the purchases need to be displayed in specific sequnce, first date first item, last date last item and then second date and second to last item and so on.
Below this there needs to be a counter of how many characters the user used to enter the item.

Comment: Would you please like to show us some code that you tried?

Comment: Please post code you have issues with directly into the question. See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Simply giving us the requirements what you need done is not what SO is for. See What Questions [**Are On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones [**Are not On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far. Actually, I can only return values form the first column with this one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function showInput() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById("user_input", "user_input2").value;
    
    }
  </script>

  </head>
<body>

  <form>
    <label>Date:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
    <label>Item:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input2">
  </form>
  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>

  <label>The user has purchased: </label>
  <p><span id='display'></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solutioon in meantime, in case anyone needs:

```
    <script type="text/JavaScript">

        var polje = [];
        var ispis = "";


        function addItem(){
            var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
            var item = document.getElementById("item").value;
            var score = { 'datum': date, 'item': item };
            field.push(score);
            console.log(score);
            printItem();
        }

        function printItem() {
          display_message.innerHTML = "";
          var outputText = "";

          sort();


          for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            outputText = outputText + field[i].datum + ", " + field[i].item + "<br/>";
            console.log(field[i]);
            console.log(outputText);
          }

          display_message.innerHTML = outputText;
        }

        function sort() {
          field.sort(function(a,b) {
            return new Date(a.datum) - new Date(b.datum);
          });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Date: <input type="date" id = "date">
Item: <input type="text" id = "item">
<input type="submit" onclick="addItem()" value="Submit" />
<p> Result: <br>
  <span id = "display_message"></span> </p>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
i = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").keypress(function(){
        $("span").text(i += 1);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Keypresses: <span>0</span></p>
</body>
</html>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```